# Finding the position of a moving point

Tags: geometry, circles, classical-mechanics

A point is moving on a given curve.
For example, curve equation is:

$$x^2 + y^2 - 10y = 0,$$

which is a circle with $5$ meter radius.

If point is on $(0,0)$ at $t = 0$ and is moving on the curve with speed $0.5$ m/s clockwise,
how to calculate the position of point at $t$ seconds (suppose $t = 5$)?

Comment: I would be tempted to move the circle down by $5$, solve the problem, and move the answer up by $5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas As you wish, but please solve it!!

Comment: It is very late. If it remains unsolved tomorrow (unlikely), and I can find it, I will write a solution.

Comment: @Akshat I did the easy bit below, it's _your_ assignment! People downvote if they sense a lack of effort.

Comment: @Akshat: Your last comment to André seems as though you are asking him to do your homework. The purpose of this site is not to do your homework for you, but to help you understand the math. Then you should attempt your own homework.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't mean that. I know very well about stack exchange guidelines! I just expressed it wrong what I was trying to say

Comment: @mistermarko thanks, I'll do it

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tau = 2\pi$ denote the ratio of the circle's circumference $C$ to its radius $r$:
$$\tau = \frac{C}{r} \implies C = \tau r = 5 \tau \mbox{ m}$$
Let $d$ be the displacement:
$$v = \frac{d}{t} \implies d = vt = (0.5 \mbox{ m/s}) \cdot (5 \mbox{ s}) = 2.5 \mbox{ m}$$
Let $P$ be the proportion moved around the circle:
$$P = \frac{2.5 \mbox{ m}}{5 \tau \mbox{ m}} = \frac{1}{2 \tau}$$
Let $\theta$ be the angle moved through:
$$\theta = P \cdot \tau = \frac12$$

Then form an isosceles triangle with the base as the line between the two points:

[image: illustration of the triangle]

The problem is now: we have two $5 \mbox{ m}$ lines whose ends join at a point at an angle of $1/2 \mbox{ rad}$ to each other. Calculate the end of the second line given the equation of the first line.

Comment: Here's a [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also personally I think it's best to avoid $\tau$ as to avoid confusion.

Comment: The downvoter should explain why I'm wrong otherwise it means nothing. Or maybe he/she is a pi fanatic?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think this answer would be substantially improved if it is changed to use mathjax and pi instead of tau. I not because I hate the tau movement but because tau is not widely known like pi is, and it could cause confusion. If you insist on using tau, atleast add a note explaining what tau is.

Comment: To the editor: units can be treated algebraically, that's why I left them in.

Comment: @mistermarko I rolled-back to your original version, with units and explanations (now it's _just_ "LaTeX-ified", and not more).

Answer (score 2):

In what follows, angles are measured in radians.

Move the circle downward by $5$ to standard position.  After the move, our starting point is $(0,-5)$.

We are travelling at $0.5$ meters per second. So in time $t$ we travel a distance $(0.5)t$.  Let us find the **angle** we have travelled through. A complete revolution is $(2\pi)(5)$, so in time $t$ we have travelled through $\frac{0.5t}{(2\pi)(5)}$ of a complete revolution.

It follows that we have travelled through an angle $(0.5 t)/5$, that is, $0.1 t$.

If we were travelling **counterclockwise** starting at $(5,0)$, we would after time $t$ be at the point $(5\cos(0.1t), 5\sin(0.1t))$.  But we are going clockwise. So if we started at $(5,0)$, after time $t$ we would be at $(5\cos(-0.1t), 5\sin(-0.1t))$.  Rewrite this as $(5\cos(0.1t), -5\sin(0.1t))$.

But we started at $(0,-5)$.  Thus after time $t$, we are at $(5\cos(0.1t+\pi/2), -5\sin(0.1t+\pi/2))$.  This is more simply written as
$$(-5\sin(0.1t), -5\cos(0.1t)).$$

Finally, let us push everything up by $5$, to solve the problem for the circle we were given. We get that at time $t$ our position is given by
$$x=-5\sin(0.1t),\qquad y= 5-5\cos(0.1t).$$

**Remark:** We used a technique sometimes called *Transform, Solve, Transform Back*. One can use the reasoning above to develop a general formula, with arbitrary circle, and arbitrary initial position on that circle.